# Sharepoint 2010 site stop automatically after restarting then work properly getting below error in event log

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Failure trying to synch web application ab6c1c01-8989-4f5d-8832-a7334a04024d, ContentDB db31bbeb-8a30-42dd-adb0-1ca4cc7029d2  Exception message was System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The site with the id 0679bb31-50fb-48a3-bdd6-ffdeb72645b8 could not be found.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id, SPFarm farm, SPUrlZone zone, SPUserToken userToken)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer.AddRemoveSites(String strFirstChangeToken, SPChangeToken lastChangeToken)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer.SynchContentDB()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.ULS.SendWatsonOnExceptionTag(UInt32 tagID, ULSCatBase categoryID, String output, Boolean fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, CatchBlock catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

The error has a few things. First the root cause of the web application stopping and erroring is the My Site Cleanup Job. However the My Site Cleanup failure looks like a symptom of orphaned sites within the SharePoint Content DB. You can see the ID's of them next to the FileNotFoundException.

As a temporary fix you can either Disable or Reschedule the MySite Cleanup Job in Central Administration. However the permanent fix to resolve the orphaned ID's is to schedule an outage window and detach, then re-attach the content database of the affected web application(s). The other methods for fixing this issue or ones I can't recommend without trying the supported approach first.

Good luck!